# zerofree on s3backer, save space in the cloud

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud

i've mounted a s3backer partition to save data on the cloud via the amazon s3 services.
As a standard filesystems behaviour, deleted files are simply unlinked from the fs leaving underlying blocks unchanged.
This cause no deletion of blocks on amazon and so the space used is billed also if was erased.
To prevent this i could use zerofree utility to force writing zero on unused blocks in the file system. This cause s3backer to delete unused block in the cloud.

The problem is that zerofree utility needs a read-only partition mounted preventing me to save space while the partition is used.

Do you know if there are other options for doing this on rw mounted partition? like filesystem mounting options or other solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously there was no good answer, but now there may be. However, there are several links in the chain that must be satisfied...

First: you need a Linux kernel supporting the `TRIM` block device command (added in 2.6.28) and a filesystem that supports it (XFS, ext4, btrfs in Linux 3.7 or later). Originally intended to inform SSD devices of blocks that they can recycle, this command tells the block device that a block is no longer needed by the filesystem using it. Some (but not all) filesystems, when a file is deleted, will inform the block device via `TRIM`.

The next link in the chain is [this kernel patch](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=dfaa2ef68e80c378e610e3c8c536f1c239e8d3ef), which in the case of a loopback mount, converts a `TRIM` block device command into an `fallocate()` using the `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` option on the looped-back file. Apparently this went into Linux in version 3.2.

The next link in the chain is support for passing the `fallocate()` system call to user code in FUSE, which was added in FUSE version 2.9.2.

The final link in the chain is support for FUSE's `fallocate()` in s3backer. I've started looking at this but it is not complete yet.

So to summarize all of the requirements (in layering order):

- An "upper" filesystem supporting `TRIM` (e.g., ext4, or btrfs in Linux >= 3.7)
- Linux kernel >= 3.2 `TRIM` on loopback mounts
- FUSE version >= 2.9.2 supporting `fallocate()`
- glibc version >= 2.18 containing the headers that define the `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` constant
- Updated version of s3backer supporting `fallocate()`

I will send something to the [s3backer mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/s3backer-devel) when this has been implemented and tested.

Comment: Well, I could not get this to work on Linux 3.4.11. For some reason with an ext4 mount using `-o loop,discard` on top of s3backer's `file`, deleting a large file doesn't result in any `falllocate()` notification being sent to the s3backer process.

Comment: Yea! It works on Linux 3.8. Apparently the FUSE filesystem in Linux 3.4 doesn't support `FALLOC_FL_PUNCH_HOLE` but the one in 3.8 does.

Comment: I found out the Linux version you need is 3.5 or later. [This web page](https://code.google.com/p/s3backer/wiki/UnsedBlockDeletion) has the gory details.